# sharepoint cannot export all fields to spreadsheet

Tags: windows, sharepoint, microsoft-excel

I am trying to make an export of a list in SharePoint to an Excel spreadsheet. I have added all needed fields to my default view of the list, (like Publishing Start Date / End date) but some fields (like Publishing Start Date / End date) don't show up in Excel. Any idea?

**EDIT:**

My setup is a MOSS standard edition, the needed fields (Publishing Start Date / End date) are standard SharePoint publishing fields.

The versions of Excel I tried it with are 2003 and 2007

Comment: So no error, they just don't appear?

Comment: Exactly, it looks like the fields that get exported are the same that are shown in the DispForm...

Comment: Is there a way to change which fields are shown in DispForm?

Comment: Maybe through SP Designer but is it DispForm or some attribute on the fields?

Comment: The DispForm uses the ListFormWebPart to display fields with rendermode = display. The in turn Calls the DocumentLibraryForm ControlTemplate from the DefaltTemplates.ascx file. I looked into that file, but it seems it uses the DocumentLibraryFields control to actually render the fields... Not sure where that control gets it's list of controls to render from...

Comment: I expect when i find that out I know how fix the export problem as well..

Comment: Hmm, tried to edit the DispForm, added a DataFormWebPart, the datasource shows the PubStart and PubExp dates, won;t be rendered in XSL though, this is gettign weirder by the minute...

Comment: SharePoint's good with being weird.

Comment: Don't get me started....

Comment: is it possible the fields are hidden?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a personalized view for which you can choose to display any field you have permissions for. This should allow you to select the missing columns, view, and export them.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a date format error but you should provide more information. 
Does it concern MOSS or WSS, which version, and which version of Excel.